# How to create my style based on SubheaderTextBlockStyle

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a new style based on an existing style 'SubheaderTextBlockStyle'.

I did:

```
 <Style x:Key="HeaderTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock"  BasedOn="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">
```

But It can't compile, I get message saying 'Style BasedOn property must be a Style, not 'ThemeResourceExtension' object.

How to get around that problem?

Comment: I think you should add the tag XAML in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubheaderTextBlockStyle` is a WP8.1 runtime thing.

This works for me using the WP8.1 RT template.  Where are you defining your `<Style>`?

```XAML
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="HeaderTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="TEST" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

---

[image]

Comment: This is actually not a solution, since you just replaced ThemeResource with the StaticResource. As stated in MSDN, "The difference is that a ThemeResource can re-evaluate at run-time and a StaticResource can't." So applying the workaround above you're basically disabling theme change detection and redrawing in your app in favor of an automatic style.